# Bean Creation Exception spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

I am self learning spring boot and trying to do a web project which would automatically post to a url(/messages) in this case and return the result.It was working fine until I thought of persisting the data to the database. There are Bean creation exceptions which are nested and I am not able to figure out what is going wrong. I have been working with spring since 2-3 days and have been trying JPA,DAO hibernate etc to connect to database. I have uploaded my project below so that it would be easy to import and check. Any help on this would be of great help. Any suggestions to understand the error and troubleshooting method would help me learn it better. I have searched resources on internet but was unable to understand why it is happening.

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByA5YjrulxrGdk05SjJjNU55LUE/view?usp=sharing
```

Stack Trace is as follows:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.3.5.RELEASE)

2016-06-29 07:36:51.479  INFO 2008 --- [           main] starter.MarkableApplication              : Starting MarkableApplication on Kranthi with PID 2008 (C:\Users\Kranthi\mars\workspace\Markable\target\classes started by Kranthi in C:\Users\Kranthi\mars\workspace\Markable)
2016-06-29 07:36:51.488  INFO 2008 --- [           main] starter.MarkableApplication              : The following profiles are active: base
2016-06-29 07:36:51.632  INFO 2008 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@525b461a: startup date [Wed Jun 29 07:36:51 MST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-06-29 07:36:54.531  INFO 2008 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$40386111] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-06-29 07:36:55.150  INFO 2008 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2016-06-29 07:36:55.169  INFO 2008 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2016-06-29 07:36:55.170  INFO 2008 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.33
2016-06-29 07:36:55.331  INFO 2008 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2016-06-29 07:36:55.332  INFO 2008 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3710 ms
2016-06-29 07:36:55.779  INFO 2008 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2016-06-29 07:36:55.786  INFO 2008 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2016-06-29 07:36:55.787  INFO 2008 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2016-06-29 07:36:55.787  INFO 2008 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2016-06-29 07:36:55.787  INFO 2008 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2016-06-29 07:36:56.147  INFO 2008 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2016-06-29 07:36:56.164  INFO 2008 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2016-06-29 07:36:56.293  INFO 2008 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.11.Final}
2016-06-29 07:36:56.296  INFO 2008 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2016-06-29 07:36:56.298  INFO 2008 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2016-06-29 07:36:56.583  INFO 2008 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
2016-06-29 07:36:57.066  INFO 2008 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2016-06-29 07:36:57.115  INFO 2008 --- [           main] o.h.h.i.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory    : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2016-06-29 07:36:57.392  INFO 2008 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
2016-06-29 07:36:57.395  INFO 2008 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000230: Schema export complete
2016-06-29 07:36:57.480  WARN 2008 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void controller.MessageController.setMessageService(service.MessageService); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void service.MessageService.setMessageRepository(repository.MessageRepository); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [repository.MessageRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
2016-06-29 07:36:57.484  INFO 2008 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2016-06-29 07:36:57.485  INFO 2008 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
2016-06-29 07:36:57.485  INFO 2008 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000230: Schema export complete
2016-06-29 07:36:57.500  INFO 2008 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
2016-06-29 07:36:57.517 ERROR 2008 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void controller.MessageController.setMessageService(service.MessageService); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void service.MessageService.setMessageRepository(repository.MessageRepository); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [repository.MessageRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at starter.MarkableApplication.main(MarkableApplication.java:25) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void controller.MessageController.setMessageService(service.MessageService); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void service.MessageService.setMessageRepository(repository.MessageRepository); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [repository.MessageRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:661) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void service.MessageService.setMessageRepository(repository.MessageRepository); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [repository.MessageRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:618) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void service.MessageService.setMessageRepository(repository.MessageRepository); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [repository.MessageRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:661) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [repository.MessageRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:618) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 32 common frames omitted

2016-06-29 07:36:57.520  INFO 2008 --- [           main] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/C:/Users/Kranthi/mars/workspace/Markable/target/classes/, file:/C:/Users/Kranthi/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Kranthi/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Kranthi/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Kranthi/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Kranthi/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Kranthi/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.7/logback-classic-1.1.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/Kranthi/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.7/logback-core-1.1.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/Kranthi/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.21/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.21.jar, file:/C:/Users/Kranthi/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.21/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.21.jar, file:/C:/Users/Kranthi/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.16/snakeyaml-1.16.jar, file:/C:/Users/Kranthi/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Kranthi/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.0.33/tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar, file:/C:/Users/Kranthi/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/8.0.33/tomcat-embed-el-8.0.33.jar, file:/C:/Users/Kranthi/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-logging-juli/8.0.33/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-8.0.33.jar, file:/C:/Users/Kranthi/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/8.0.33/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.33.jar, file:/C:/Users/Kranthi/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-validation/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-validation-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Kranthi/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.2.4.Final/hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Kranthi/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Kranthi/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.1.0/classmate-1.1.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/Kranthi/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.6.6/jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar, file:/C:/Users/Kranthi/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.6.6/jackson-annotations-2.6.6.jar, file:/C:/Users/Kranthi/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.6.6/jackson-core-2.6.6.jar, file:/C:/Users/Kranthi/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Kranthi/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Kranthi/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/Kranthi/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Kranthi/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Kranthi/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Kranthi/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Kranthi/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-core-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Kranthi/.m2/repository/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.38/mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar, file:/C:/Users/Kranthi/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Kranthi/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-aop/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-aop-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Kranthi/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.8.9/aspectjweaver-1.8.9.jar, file:/C:/Users/Kranthi/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Kranthi/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-jdbc/8.0.33/tomcat-jdbc-8.0.33.jar, file:/C:/Users/Kranthi/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-juli/8.0.33/tomcat-juli-8.0.33.jar, file:/C:/Users/Kranthi/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-jdbc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Kranthi/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/4.3.11.Final/hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Kranthi/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.3.0.Final/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Kranthi/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging-annotations/1.2.0.Beta1/jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Kranthi/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/4.3.11.Final/hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Kranthi/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/Kranthi/.m2/repository/org/jboss/jandex/1.1.0.Final/jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Kranthi/.m2/repository/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Kranthi/.m2/repository/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.0.b2/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar, file:/C:/Users/Kranthi/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations/4.0.5.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Kranthi/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/1.0.0.Final/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Kranthi/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.18.1-GA/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar, file:/C:/Users/Kranthi/.m2/repository/javax/transaction/javax.transaction-api/1.2/javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/Kranthi/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-jpa/1.9.4.RELEASE/spring-data-jpa-1.9.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Kranthi/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/1.11.4.RELEASE/spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Kranthi/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-orm/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-orm-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Kranthi/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-tx-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Kranthi/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.21/slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar, file:/C:/Users/Kranthi/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.21/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.21.jar, file:/C:/Users/Kranthi/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aspects/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-aspects-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar]
```

Application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/messages
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=X9pgptjaud6@

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.profiles.active=base
```

P.S : please do not down vote this question as it is my genuine attempt to learn spring boot, and down voting would bar me from asking any more questions which hinders my learning.

Comment: Would you please include the exception stacktrace in your post?

Comment: Can you post your properties / yml file, where you configured your database properties?

Comment: This is what i saw on first glance. remove the setter that you have for message service on the controller and just add the autowire annotation on top of private MessageService messageService.

Comment: @Grinish : I have tried that, the error still is the same

Answer (score -1):

Your repository package is missing in `@Componentscan` package list. Also, your `MessageRepository` class is missing `@Repository` annotations.

One suggestion though, Have a common package for all other packages, like `com.demo.service`, `com.demo.repository` etc. Now you can just use `@Componentscan(basePackages = "com.demo")`. So, you won't "accidentally" forget any packages. However, keep your application class in the common package (**`com.demo`**) itself. Something like this.

```
package com.demo;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.demo")
public class MarkableApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ....
}
```

I am not sure, why this is necessary. But I also had trouble in the past having `Application.class` in separate  package. After I moved to common package, I was able to build.
Also, add the `@Autowired` to field in your `MessageService` class and get rid of setter method.

```
@Autorwired
private MessageRepository messagerepository;
```

Comment: were you able to try these? I have changed these settings but the error still remained same..

Comment: @kranthikumar Edited the answer. Check it out.

Comment: Also, look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38127911/1257729) answer about structuring your application.