# 404 error if controller not in Application.java package. @ComponentScan not working [Resolved]

Tags: spring-boot

I am having trouble with spring-boot setting up a simple application when the Application.java, controller (@Controller), services (@Service) and repositories (@Repository) are in different packages.

I know it's a common issue and I've found here that it's a matter of setting up the @ComponentScan annotation in the main class.

However, despite doing this, I still get a 404 error when I try to access my REST service.

Here's my project structure :

```
main
├── java
│   ├── application
│   │   └── Application.java
│   ├── controllers
│   │   └── CategoryController.java
│   ├── dto
│   │   └── ReturnMessage.java
│   ├── entities
│   │   ├── Category.java
│   │   ├── Post.java
│   │   └── User.java
│   ├── repositories
│   │   └── CategoryRepository.java
│   ├── services
│   │   ├── CategoryService.java
│   │   └── CategoryServiceImpl.java
│   └── utils
│       └── Constants.java
```

Here's my Application.java :

```java
package application;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@EnableJpaRepositories
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("main.java")
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

And the beginning of my CategoryController.java :

```java
@RestController
public class CategoryController {

    @Autowired
    CategoryService categoryService;

    /**
     * Retourne la liste des catégories
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = Constants.REST_BASE_URL + "/categories", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Category> readAll() {
        return categoryService.readAll();
    }
```

Constants.REST_BASE_URL is "rest/", and I get a 404 error when I call localhost:8080/rest/categories. I tried removing the base URL and it changed nothing. It works if I put the controller in the Application.java class.

Any guess as to why it is not working ? I'm new to Spring-boot so there may be something obvious that I forgot to do.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your `@ComponentScan` annotation. You've configured it to look in a package named `main.java`, however you have no such package in your application. The packages that you do have are:

- `application`
- `controllers`
- `dto`
- `entities`
- `repositories`
- `services`
- `utils`

You could list all of these packages:

```
@ComponentScan({"application", "controllers", "dto", "entities", "repositories", "services", "utils"})
```

However, this would be rather unconventional.

It's more conventional for all of your packages to have a common root. If you place your `Application` class in this package there's then no need for an explicit `@ComponentScan` at all. Something like this:

```
main
├── java
|   |   foo
│   │   ├── Application.java
|   │   ├── controllers
|   │   │   └── CategoryController.java
|   │   ├── dto
|   │   │   └── ReturnMessage.java
|   │   ├── entities
│   │   ├── Category.java
│   │   ├── Post.java
│   │   ├── User.java
|   │   ├── repositories
|   │   │   └── CategoryRepository.java
|   │   ├── services
|   │   │   ├── CategoryService.java
|   │   │   └── CategoryServiceImpl.java
|   │   └── utils
|   │       └── Constants.java
```

Your package names would now be:

- `foo`
- `foo.controllers`
- `foo.dto`
- `foo.entities`
- `foo.repositories`
- `foo.services`
- `foo.utils`

And your `Application` class being in the `foo` package will meant that component scanning is enabled for it and all of its sub-packages without you having to explicitly configure it.

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm. I should have known better but I was stuck with tunnel vision on the @ComponentScan rather than see the error in the package hierarchy.